# Contextmenu with bootstrap dropdown not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, contextmenu

I am trying to display a Twitter Bootstrap dropdown menu on right click on a element. This is the code that I wrote:

#### Javascript

```
var toggle = $('.dropdown-toggle');
toggle.on('contextmenu',function(e){
  toggle.dropdown('toggle');
  return false;
});
```

#### HTML

```
<div class="dropdown"> <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dropdown trigger</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>Hello</li>
        <li>World</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This code works fine in Chrome and when I right click the menu is displayed properly, but on Firefox when I right click, the menu is displayed for a second and it disappears. Is there any other event that I need to handle too?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Serff/3/

Answer (score 1):

Remove

```
data-toggle="dropdown"
```

The final html markup:

```
<div class="dropdown">
   <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Dropdown trigger</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
    <li>Hello</li>
    <li>World</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This should work.

Use this script:

```
var toggle = $('.dropdown-toggle');
toggle.on('contextmenu',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  toggle.dropdown('toggle');
});
```

Comment: Thanks. It works for the contextmenu, but I also want the menu to be displayed when the link is clicked.

Comment: This fix does not work in Chrome. The default functionality of the dropdown stops working.
I found that this is a known issue in Firefox as it fires an event on the document for every contextmenu event. Bootstrap adds a click event listener on the document to close/toggle dropdowns, it causes the dropdown to hide on a right click.